# Python openpyxl.reader.excel reading data

Tags: python, openpyxl

Hello all I am reading one xlsx file using python openpyxl module. when i am reading this file its changing its date format of date in xlsx. how can i get same value as they are in excel file. my code is

```
def xlsxToxCsv(inputfile, outfile):
    start = time.clock()
    wb=load_workbook(inputfile)
    for sheet in wb.worksheets:
        csv_file=outfile
        print 'Creating %s' % csv_file
        fd=open(csv_file, 'wt')
        for row in sheet.rows:
            values=[]
#            print row
            for cell in row:
                value=cell.value
                if sheet.is_date(value):
                    print value
#                print value
                if value is None:
                    value=''
                if not isinstance(value, unicode):
                    value=unicode(value)
                value=value.encode('utf8')
                value = "\""+value+"\""
                values.append(value)
#            print (','.join(values))
#            print values
            fd.write(','.join(values))
            fd.write('\n')
        fd.close()
        end = time.clock()
        print 'Code time %.6f seconds' % (end - start)
        return csv_file
```

can any one help me to get same value of excel file. in excel file date is like 4/27/2009 but in csv i am getting 2009-06-12 00:00:00 like.

Comment: What is not working for you? what is your result when running the code? In any case, change your variable `end` to something else as it is a saved word in python.

Comment: when i am reading value from xlsx file the date is in xlsx file like 4/27/2009 but when i am getting value `value=cell.value` by this code its printing like 2009-06-12 00:00:00.

Comment: end variable is nothing its just checking my processing time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `print value` line prints the default representation of `value`, a `datetime` object. Check out the documentation to see how to format it in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Pass dates through this function to get the date values.

```
def make_date(xlnum):
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import timedelta
    year = timedelta(days=xlnum)
    my_birthday = date(1899, 12, 30)
    return my_birthday + year
```